# Google sheet custom function: Reading arrays in the script vs passing from a sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to javascript. I'm having fun with it.

I'm puzzled that if I pass an array in a custom function in google sheets I get diffent dimensioned arrays within an array. Reading across 5 columns gets me an array with 5 elements in an array with 1. If I read down 5 rows I get a 5 one element arrays in one array.

Rerferences for everything in the passed array are either, say: Array[0][2] or Array[2][0] depending on how the array was passed.

I can handle this in the script, but with quite a few lines of codes with conditionals and for each array passed. I can't beleive that's necessary. The regular functions (eg: sum(a1:a5 vs sum(a1:e1)) are indifferent to the array that's passed and I can't believe they all have to do this.

I imagine there's a simpler way to handle this than what I've done and would love to know.
Thanks.

This is how I"m handling it now. values [] is what's passed from a custom function.
(Like I said, I'm new to this)

```
var NuValues = []
if (values.length <=1 && values[0].length <=1){  
    return 'more than one value required'
} else if(values.length>1 && !Array.isArray(values[0])){
      // already a 1d array and can be handled 
       NuValues = values.slice()
}  else if (values.length ==1 && values[0].length >1){
      //read across columns, read to a flat array
      //read values across columns
      NuValues = values[0].slice()
  
} else if (values.length>1 && values[0].length == 1){
      //(read values down a column
      for(i=0; i<=values.length-1;i++){
         NuValues.push(values[i][0])
      }
}
console.log(NuValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a 1D array that contains all the values in a 2D array, use `Array.flat()`, like this:

```
  values = values.flat();
```

You can use that safely with 1D arrays as well.

To make it work in the event `values` is not an array but a single value, use this:

```
  if (Array.isArray(values)) {
    values = values.flat();
  } else {
    values = [values];
  }
```

This will convert a single value, a 1D array or a 2D array all to a 1D array. You can then use `Array` methods without a need to further examine the dimensions of `values`.